# Do AMD PSP's have TPM?

Tags: tpm

I was recently wondering about systems which can protect a computer against firmware malware. A user on Information Security said that the an attempt to make a computer more secure is the TPM system.

Do AMD Platform Security Processors have TPM or something similar to it? If so, then which laptops with AMD PSP's have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AMD PSPs have a firmware-based TPM 2.0 (i.e. fTPM) implementation according to [this page](https://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2018/Jan/12).

Note that *usually* the TPM is a completely separate chip connected via LPC, and does not need to be embedded within the system CPU. Many "business" laptops have a discrete TPM (for BitLocker).